# How to set cursor at the end of line for text-box in nightwatch

Tags: nightwatch.js

I want to click at the end of text for text-box and write some text there. when I use .keys() it begins to append in middle

Answer (score 0):

This might work in selenium `Sendkeys` but not in Nightwatch js as far as I know.

You can achieve what you are trying to do by doing the below steps.

- Read the current value in the field
- Append the text you want to add
- Clear the content of the field
- Keys can be used to set the full text into the field.

Comment: can't we append from end of text without clearing existing one?

Comment: that is the only way I can see if setValue (as mentioned in below answer) doesn't work in your case and you have to go with `keys`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use .setValue() ?

From the API link https://nightwatchjs.org/api/setValue.html:

> setValue does not clear the existing value of the element. To do so,
>   use the clearValue() command.

Comment: i don't want to clear exisiting text, instead i want to append in it

Comment: So, it should be worked with setValue (). Don't call clearValue() in you case. That's all.